# Prepared Statements in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, prepared-statement

I wanted to use prepared statements in my nodejs code using sequelize so I tried using sequelize with .query method but how could I use this to throw en error when a sql injected statement is provided as a parameter for the sql statement

```
const query = "select distinct c.id from categories c where eventId=?";
let eventId = 123;
const response = await db.sequelize.query(query,
{ 
    replacements: [eventId],
    type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
});
 return response;
```

Comment: For such simple parameters it's better to use `bind` option instead of `replacements` so you can pass this parameter to DB as a static value and the DB driver processes it itself as a parameter value not trying to parse it

Comment: Even If I use bind I want to throw an error message when someone tries using sql injection

Comment: How can you detect SQL injection for sure? I suppose it's quite difficult in general. Yes, you can detect simple cases but not all of them

Comment: In this specific case, your error handling for sql injection is on eventId. If evnetId a numeric number => execute .query, else throw error. throw error at .query is too late. sql injection is happened yet. anything passed to .query should be already validated escaped query.  but honestly, if you want to use Sequelize, you should use `findAll`, `findOne`, etc instead of `query`. these functions already take care of escaping so that sql injection is prevented.  Use `query` only if you have a complex query that you cannot convert to Sequelize.

Comment: Yeah this is only a simplified version of the query I have, and this eventId sometimes is a string and sometimes is an integer, I was thinking if anyone could embbed the sql injected statement into another form as a number and then when using prepared statement if I could detect this condition I could give an error @Emma

Comment: @Anatoly How could I detect them for majority of cases?

Comment: For a static structure of input data you can use validators like `joi` to check either you have valid input parameters/request body or not.. And still try to use Sequelize models and `bind` in case of using `query` as much as possible